# how to run a script on shutdown after all the user process have been stopped?

Tags: script, shutdown

I have setup a auto scaled load balanced application on Amazon EC2. I want to collect the logs from the auto scaled instances before automatic termination of the instances.

I have a script which transfers files from the auto scaled instances to a Centralize log server. I want to run the script on shutdown or reboot of the instances.
I am using Fedora, please let me know how to run the script on shutdown after all the user process have been stopped ?

Comment: Note that to do the transfer you'll have to do it before networking is shut down, otherwise you won't be able to do the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Write an initscript that performs the task in `stop()`. See `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles` for details.

Comment: I created a file transferlogs with the following contents    #!/bin/bash
start(){
}
stop() {
        echo -n "Shutting down logtransfer status: "
        cd /etc/init.d/
        ./logtransfer
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    reload)
        ;;
esac
exit 0

Comment: chmod +x /etc/init.d/transferlogs  and restarted the system. But the logs were not transferred to the other server.

Comment: Your script is missing a *lot* of required boilerplate. Read that file again.